# Some tables id column do not auto increment despite being identity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am troubleshooting a db (not my forte) that has some tables that are auto incrementing on the id column and some tables are not?

Now all the tables are set as identity and marked to disallow null. I am using SSMS what else can I check or do to get these tables back to auto incrementing?

TIA

Interestingly to me...probably old news to you guys. The issue had to do with existing data. So for example a table that had 100 rows in did *NOT* have the identity column setup. So I would go in and make it an identity with a seed of 1 incrementing 1. Well the seed was somehow having trouble because there was already 100 rows in there. So for all my tables I had to do a row count and seed the identity from the next row. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an `IDENTITY` column is pretty straightforward for a table, and if you are *not* seeing the auto incrementing behavior of a column on inserts, then I'd first verify that your column is indeed an `IDENTITY` column:

```
use <Your Database Name>;
go

select
    name,
    is_identity
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('<Your Table Name>')
order by column_id;
```

*Substitute `<Your Database Nam>` and `<Your Table Name>` for their appropriate values.*

The other possibility is that data that "appears" to be non-incrementing could have been pushed out to that with a session that set identity insert and pushed out explicit values.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE YourTable MODIFY COLUMN YourTable_id int(4) auto_increment`

Comment: OK I can do that as TSQL command. Out of curiosity is theree a way in SSMS?

Comment: Maybe you can find that here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/a8922362-f22a-4ec5-a7eb-9a185ee19146/autoincrement-existing-column-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Comment: That isn't valid TSQL anyway.